# Searching for text with wildcards as a where condition

Tags: sql

I have a table named "Reports"

```
+----------+--------+-----------------------------------------+--------+
| ReportID | userID |               ReportName                | Active |
+----------+--------+-----------------------------------------+--------+
|       15 |    123 | Prefix.DumbReport.1234                  |      0 |
|       16 |    123 | Prefix.DumbReport.2345                  |      0 |
|       17 |    123 | Prefix.ADifferentReport.22              |      0 |
|       18 |    123 | Prefix.SuffixesAndPrefixesAreUnreliable |      0 |
|       19 |    123 | ThisReportisActive.2345                 |      1 |
+----------+--------+-----------------------------------------+--------+
```

And I have  table named "Tasks"

```
+--------+--------+---------------------+
| TaskID | userID |   Task_Parameters   |
+--------+--------+---------------------+
|      1 |    123 | Prefix.DumbReport   |
|      2 |    123 | SuffixesAndPrefixes |
+--------+--------+---------------------+
```

I want to find a list of reports that are inactive, and **don't** have a task associated with them.  ReportName and Task_Parameters are never going to be exactly equal.  But the text inside "Task_Parameters" will always exist somewhere exactly within "ReportName"

If it matters, I'm skipping a step for the sake of clarity, but Task_Parameters is actually json, and I'm using SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX to get just the ReportName.

So in this example, I want my query to return **Report ID 17** only.

- The text contained in Task_Parameters for TaskID 1 is contained in
  ReportID 15 and 16.
- The text contained in Task_Parameters for TaskID 2 is contained in
  ReportID 18
- Report ID 19 has Active = 1, and I don't even know why I included
  this as an example, because it's just a simple "Active = 0" but I'm
  not reformatting my tables

I feel like this should be simple, but I'm getting myself all mixed up for how to query that.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find a list of reports that are inactive, and don't have a task associated with them.

You can use `not exsts` and pattern matching:

```
select r.*
from reports r
where
    r.active = 0
    and not exists (
        select 1 from tasks t where r.reportName like concat(r.task_parameter, '%')
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could LEFT JOIN on `reports.report_name LIKE '%' || tasks.task_parameters || '%'` and then find the rows `where active = 0 and task_parameters is null`

check out:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5da318fdeb016434a8b47c5c1df5e2dd

the example uses postgres 12, but any rdbms should be able to handle this